# Android create new instance of current activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I an have activity called A in my project, there is a button that create new instance of the same activity. For example i want to do something like this:

```
intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_DATA, data);
startActivity(intent);
```

If i use this code the app crashes when i push the button.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I'm going to guess, you need to declare `activity` `A` in your `AndroidManifest`

Comment: The activity is declared into manifest
    <activity android:name=".A"/>

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The activity use a object of another class called data, this class need to implement Serializable.